# Count recordset with SQL statement in Access - Runtime Error 3075

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm new to Access and trying to count the number of rows in a dataset and am using the below code. I am getting a runtime error which seems to be because of the SQL statement. I have copied it from a query so am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
Function RecordCount()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlstring As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim FindRecordCount As Integer

sqlstring = "SELECT Question_List.Questions, Question_List.[Freq] FROM Question_List WHERE (((Question_List.ClientCd)=`" & [Forms]![TestControlCreate]![ComClient] & "));"


   Set db = CurrentDb

   Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sqlstring) 

   FindRecordCount = rst.RecordCount

Return
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks HansUp no it was a mistype and it looks like it helps but Im getting a different error now - Runtime Error 3061 too few parameters. The field ClientCd is text

Answer (score 0):

The SqlString should be reconstructed in the following manner:

```
 sqlstring = "SELECT Question_List.[Questions], Question_List.[Freq] FROM Question_List WHERE Question_List.[ClientCd]= '" & [Forms].[TestControlCreate].[ComClient] & "';"
```